# Multiple conditions for loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I was trying to use a multiple value in a for loop. if I create two separate for loops, the code is repeated twice, so I tried this:

```
for ((NSString* Key in [Dictionary allKeys]) && (NSString* Key2 in [Dictionary allValues])){
```

But no way!! How can I do it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, variable names should start with a lower case letter.

Do you know the "usual" form of a for loop? The one you're using is just a short cut for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
    id obj = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
    // do something with the object
}
```

So in your case, you could write

```
NSArray *allKeys = [dictionary allKeys];
for (int i = 0; i < [allKeys count]; i++) {
    NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
    NSObject *obj = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary` provides a special block-based method for this:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with key and obj
}];
```

Comment: I tried adding this, but it did not work. What does it permit you to? The main problem I have now is that the data is not displayed in order, but mixed up. Will this solve the problem??

Comment: Of course it is not sorted. The keys of a dictionary have an undefined order by definition. If you want to sort the keys, get them nto an array with `allKeys` and sort that array. Then iterate over the array as some of the other answers show.

Answer (score 1):

The for-in loop doesn't work like this. It takes exactly one object which implements the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol and loops over all values, nothing less and nothing more. If you need to use the key and the value inside your loop you'll have to get the value for the key:

```
for (id key in dictionary) {
   id value = [dictionary valueForKey: key];
   // do stuff with key and value
}
```

Note that you don't need to enumerate over `[dictionary allKeys]`, `NSDictionary` implements `NSFastEnumeration` to enumerate over the keys.

If you don't want to do the lookup for the values yourself and you target an OS where blocks are available (iOS 4.0 and Mac OS X 10.6 or later) you can use the block-based method `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:`:

```
[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^( id key, id value, BOOL *stop ) {
    // do stuff with key and value
}];
```

With the block-based method you set `*stop` to `YES` to break out of the loop while you can use `break` in a regular loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the two arrays before iterating over their content:

```
NSMutableArray *allKeysAndValues = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[Dictionary allKeys]];
[allKeysAndValues addObjectsFromArray:[Dictionary allValues]];
for (NSString* KeyOrValue in allKeysAndValues) {
    // Do something...
}
```

A better approach would be enumerating your dictionary with a *block*, like this:

```
[Dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@", key, object);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Just looking at the line, there a semantic issue for the compiler. Does this mean iterate Key and Key2 simultaneously in parallel? Does it mean only get in the loop if both Keys are non-nil? Does it mean iterate through the concatenation of the two sets? etc...

It sounds to me like your Dictionary might not be the right data structure for what you want to do.

Won't this work for what you are trying to do?

```
for (NSString* Key in [Dictionary allKeys]) {
    NSString* Key2 = [Dictionary objectForKey:Key]?
    // ...
}
```

Or you can try to concatenate both sets in a single array and iterate then if that's the behavior you want.